# Isotope - filtering with URL hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I use this (see source code) : [isotope filter](http://www.eskem-studio.com/Lehmann/portfolio-4columns2.html)
but i need to be abble to make a link to cats filtered items (for example) or any other.
Basically i need to do exactly the same as this : [Url hash](http://s.codepen.io/desandro/debug/vErxXj#filter=numberGreaterThan50) with parameter in the url so i can link directly to a filtered result.
Whit the code i use jquery.isotope.sloppy-masonry.min.js, jquery.isotope.min.js what is the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Jquery BBQ to solve my problem, with this method :
[Hash History](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/hash-history-jquery-bbq.html)